# How to see the log of specific activity on Mojave?

Tags: logs

There are applications (eg. timing app.com) which once installed can log one's daily activity (websites visited, docs opened, time spent on an app etc.), but how can one do this without installing software - ie. on console. What are the specific commands for listing which apps were open when, and history of network activity.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  As currently written, your question is overly broad and could be subject to downvotes and closure.  See [ask] for tips on asking questions here.  You can [edit] your question to add the missing info.

Comment: The log file is stored in the /private/var/log directory.  You can go to that directory and use simple *nix commands to extract the lines you want or from the Mac Finder, you can right-click on the system.log file and "open with" the editor of choice and use that editor to extract the lines you want.

Comment: You can roll your own via terminal commands or you can pay for some app that has already done this work.  It will be far less hassle to buy an app. There is not guarantee the log will contain all the information you need.

Comment: Perhaps fs_usage (https://ss64.com/osx/fs_usage.html) - if web usage then fs_usage Safari and so on. However, filtering using a suggested fs_usage | grep doesn't seem to help much (https://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os_x_using_fs_usage_as_a_troubleshooting_tool). For example, if I use fs_usage Safari then search for "www" I can see web access. Folder paths are also available, but not sure how to filter opening them initially.